# map array with condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have array like

```
 strings = ["by_product[]=1", "by_product[]=2", "page=1", "per_page=10", "select[]=current", "select[]=requested", "select[]=original"]
```

which is array of params from request

Then there is code that generates hash from array

```
arrays = strings.map do |segment|
        k,v = segment.split("=")
        [k, v && CGI.unescape(v)]
Hash[arrays]
```

CUrrent output -

```
"by_product[]": "2",
      "page":"1",
      "per_page":"10",
      "select[]":"original"
```

Expected output -

```
"by_product[]":"1, 2",
      "page":"1",
      "per_page":"10",
      "select[]":"current, requested, original"
```

The problem is - after `split` method there are few `by_product[]` and the last one just overrides any other params, so in result instead of hash with array as value of these params im getting only last one. And i'm not sure how to fix it. Any ideas? Or at least algorithms

Comment: added more information

Comment: That's not valid Ruby.. Is it a Hash or Array ?

Comment: Made it look like a hash, to simplify

Comment: What is `strings` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So try this:

```
hash = {}
arrays = strings.map do |segment|
          k,v = segment.split("=")
          hash[k]||=[]
          hash[k] << v
        end
```

output is

```
1.9.3-p547 :025 >   hash
 => {"by_product[]"=>["1", "2"], "page"=>["1"], "per_page"=>["10"], "select[]"=>["current", "requested", "original"]}
```

or if you want just strings do

```
arrays = strings.map do |segment|
          k,v = segment.split("=")
          hash[k].nil? ? hash[k] = v : hash[k] << ", " + v
        end
```

Comment: will try, and give feedback

Comment: Assuming the comma's are important in the output I would change both the hash lines on the second one to `hash[k].nil? ? hash[k] = v : hash[k] << ", " + v` personally

Comment: Yes, you are right.@Avdept, consider @Baloo's comment

Comment: @pavelS i had to change your code a little bit, so params that have no array, would be like a string and with array would be array-like

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel, CGI and Rack can already handle query strings.

Assuming your `strings` array comes from a single query string:

```
query = "by_product[]=1&by_product[]=2&page=1&per_page=10&select[]=current&select[]=requested&select[]=original"
```

you can use [`CGI::parse`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-parse): (all values as arrays)

```
require 'cgi'

CGI.parse(query)
#=> {"by_product[]"=>["1", "2"], "page"=>["1"], "per_page"=>["10"], "select[]"=>["current", "requested", "original"]}
```

or [`Rack::Utils.parse_query`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Utils#parse_query-class_method): (arrays where needed)

```
require 'rack'

Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(query)
# => {"by_product[]"=>["1", "2"], "page"=>"1", "per_page"=>"10", "select[]"=>["current", "requested", "original"]}
```

or [`Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Utils#parse_nested_query-class_method): (values without `[]` suffix)

```
require 'rack'

Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(query)
# => {"by_product"=>["1", "2"], "page"=>"1", "per_page"=>"10", "select"=>["current", "requested", "original"]}
```

And if these are parameters for a Rails controller, you can just [use `params`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters).

Answer (score 1):

this will also work :

```
strings.inject({}){ |hash, string| 
  key, value = string.split('='); 
  hash[key] = (hash[key]|| []) << value;
  hash;
}
```

output :
`{"by_product[]"=>["1", "2"], "page"=>["1"], "per_page"=>["10"], "select[]"=>["current", "requested", "original"]}`

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that

```
array.map { |record| record*3 if condition }
```

record*3 is the resultant operation you wanna do to the array while mapping